# Good books to learn Combinatorial Game Theory?

Tags: game-theory

I am currently doing my IB Diploma and we are supposed to make an extended essay on a subject of our choice- and i chose math. my research question is- "how to derive a perfect strategy to always win at the game of Nim?" - it has already been done- i know- but they aren't expecting anything groundbeaking from us- we're 17 year olds.
anyway i don't have much knowledge in CGT and i need to know which books could be suitable for my essay. obviously it should include the study of zero sum, two player determnistic games,etc.
thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

I think the classics of Combinatorial Game Theory are "*On Numbers and Games*" and the multi-volume "*Winning Ways for your Mathematical Plays*".

These go much further than [Nim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim), which has a fairly simple algorithm for perfect play.

Comment: Yes, that's the best.